# Profile all layers of a given model in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, profiling, large-language-model

I'm learning to use Pytorch profiler (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html) to profile different models.
It works really nice with the example. But when I try a different model, the output is not what I expected.

I'd like to get the time spent in different layers (q_proj, k_proj, v_proj, softmax, etc.). Having a look at the code of the model (using https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax), the layers are defined as normal pytorch layers (nn.Linear(self.embed_dim, self.embed_dim, bias=False), nn.functional.softmax, etc.).

How is the correct way to use Pytorch in such models? Do I need to modify the model?

For instance, when using Pytorch profiler with the model GPT-J (from https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gptj), I get the following output, which shows no layer but other auxiliary functions:

```
----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                  Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls  
----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
               forward        90.29%     558.000us        94.34%     583.000us     583.000us             1  
           aten::zeros         5.02%      31.000us         5.66%      35.000us      35.000us             1  
          aten::unbind         1.62%      10.000us         2.43%      15.000us      15.000us             1  
          aten::detach         0.49%       3.000us         1.29%       8.000us       8.000us             1  
          aten::select         0.65%       4.000us         0.81%       5.000us       5.000us             1  
                detach         0.81%       5.000us         0.81%       5.000us       5.000us             1  
           aten::empty         0.65%       4.000us         0.65%       4.000us       2.000us             2  
           aten::zero_         0.16%       1.000us         0.16%       1.000us       1.000us             1  
      aten::as_strided         0.16%       1.000us         0.16%       1.000us       1.000us             1  
              aten::to         0.16%       1.000us         0.16%       1.000us       1.000us             1  
    aten::resolve_conj         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
     aten::resolve_neg         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 618.000us
```

The code I'm using is:

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from torch.profiler import profile, record_function, ProfilerActivity

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model     = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B")

prompt = ("In a shocking finding, scientists discovered a herd of unicorns living in a remote, "
           "previously unexplored valley, in the Andes Mountains. Even more surprising to the "
           "researchers was the fact that the unicorns spoke perfect English."
        )

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
gen_tokens = model.generate(input_ids,
                            do_sample=True,
                            temperature=0.9,
                            max_length=100)

with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("forward"):
       gen_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(gen_tokens)[0]


print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=100))

print ("----- Group by input shape")
print(prof.key_averages(group_by_input_shape=True).table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=10))

prof.export_chrome_trace("trace.json")
```